# Compare the hash password value in mysql.user

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

Say I have a password "Foobar1234". In MySQL database (5.6), the hash value is

```
*59C0D3B7983F06CF32F555AD04BAC66BCF952597
```

I want to try this outside of MySQL database so the SQL query isn't logged. Is the hash function known? I am using the default settings.

Here is the doc: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/password-hashing.html

Answer (score 1):

This question was explained several times in the DBA StackExchange

- `Nov 21, 2013` : [Why are the passwords in MySQL (5.x) not salted?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/53735/why-are-the-passwords-in-mysql-5-x-not-salted/53748#53748) (by Michael - sqlbot)
- `Dec 26, 2013` : [MYSQL - Unable to change 'old_passwords' variable](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50610/mysql-unable-to-change-old-passwords-variable/55635#55635)
- `Apr 22, 2015` : [Why are mysql password hashes internally saved with a star (asterisk)?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98529/why-are-mysql-password-hashes-internally-saved-with-a-star-asterisk/98558#98558)

[I actually learned the formula from a post from PalominoDB (later changed name to Blackbird and then was purchased by Pythian). The post was made `Dec 4, 2011` entitled **"Hashing Algorithm In MySQL PASSWORD()"**](https://blog.pythian.com/hashing-algorithm-in-mysql-password-2/)

So if you want to execute this function yourself, it would look something like this:

```
SET @my_new_pass = 'WhateverIWantAsThePassword';
SET @my_new_hash = CONCAT('*',UPPER(SHA1(UNHEX(SHA1(@my_new_pass))))) MySQLPWDHASH;
```

This would land in the MySQL history `~/.mysql_history` but not in the binary logs.